# How to use NLP in Python to extract the 'subject' of a question using NLTK trees

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, chatbot

I am trying to figure out how to understand a question in Python. The aim is to use this for an information retrieval chatbot - i.e. the user will ask for information about something, and then the chatbot will access a knowledge base to return information about that something.

Example user inputs may be:

"Show me information about WW1." - where [WW1] should be extracted

"I want to know the symptoms of the common flu." - where [the symptoms of the common flu] should be extracted

I have started of by looking at spacy and nltk, specifically nltk trees, which end up looking like these:

```
    Show            
  ___|________       
 |   |   information
 |   |        |      
 |   |      about   
 |   |        |      
 me  .       WW1



        want                             
  _______|________                        
 |   |           know                    
 |   |    ________|______                 
 |   |   |            symptoms           
 |   |   |     __________|______          
 |   |   |    |                 of       
 |   |   |    |                 |         
 |   |   |    |                flu       
 |   |   |    |           ______|____     
 I   .   to  the        the        common
```

From here, I'm not sure how to extract the correct subtree as shown above, and I don't want to have to assume it will always be the right hand most tree.

I also don't know if this is the best way of tackling this problem?

Once I have the string value of which the user wants information about I can use this to find the information, I just need to get this value first.

Answer (score 0):

SpaCy is a good library for this type of problem. This code is similar but more informative than nltk trees, as it includes directed dependency types and part-of-speech tags.

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

doc = nlp('I want to know the symptoms of the common flu.')

# retokenize noun chunk spans
spans = spacy.util.filter_spans(doc.noun_chunks)
with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
    [retokenizer.merge(span, attrs={"tag": span.root.tag, "dep": span.root.dep})for span in spans]


options = {"compact": True, "font": "Source Sans Pro"}
displacy.serve(doc, style="dep", options=options) # see on http://localhost:5000/
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try stanford's dependancy parser. It analyzes the grammatical structure of a sentence and provides information like pos tags dependency relations , from which you can easily identify subject and objects in a given sentence. Check the website https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/nndep.html.